# Powershell button image

Tags: image, button, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to use jpgs for button images in a Powershell form. I tried this code:

```
#Add Image to Button
$image = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.Image
$image.Source = "C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\Avengers.jpg"
$image.Stretch = 'Fill'
$button.Content = $image
```

From: http://learn-powershell.net/2012/10/01/powershell-and-wpf-buttons/

The script is throwing an error: 
Cannot find type[System.Controls.Image]: Make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.

I tried to use another assembly from the script to figure this one out:
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')

I'm stuck on version, culture, and PublicKeyToken (I started the script in Powershell Studio, but I'm finishing it in Notepad++). How can I best get this information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You picked a cool language to do .Net development in!! It's a bit difficult though, since there is very little documentation to help out.

Instead of using System.Controls.Image, try System.Drawing.Image:

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Drawing
$image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("C:\users\Administrator\Desktop\Avengers.jpg")
$button.Image = $image
```

Comment: Thank you, again. This time, I didn't wait five hours to ask...:/
You're not kidding about the documentation.

Comment: I wanted to say thanks again. My final project for CS50 is almost done, and I would've struggled much more without your help. Thank you.